# Removing disorder from linked list

Tags: c

I'm trying to do an exercise where I have to ensure that all elements in my linked list are ordered (essentially the list should be in ascending order), if any element is greater than the next element it is deleted and freed from memory. This is my current try:

```
struct node *remove_disorder(struct node *head) {
    struct node *curr = head;
    struct node *prev = head;


    if (curr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (curr->next == NULL) {
        return head;
    }

    struct node *temp = NULL;
    while (curr->next != NULL) {
        while (curr->data > curr->next->data) {
            if (curr == head) {
                prev = curr->next;
                free(curr);
                curr = prev;
                curr->next = prev->next;
                head = prev;
            } else {
                prev->next = curr->next;
                temp = curr;
                curr = prev;
                curr->next = prev->next;
                free(temp);
            }
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;

    }
    return head;
}
```

The compiler is telling me that I'm accessing already freed memory in `while (curr->data > curr->next->data)` even though I assign curr a new value after freeing it. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have written lots of needless code. Please try to refactor :)

Comment: The whole code needs refactoring, except for the inital 2 if checks. Please take a pen and paper and debug the logic; as it is not much to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some redundant assignments. After `node2 = node1` assignment, it's needless to assign `node2->next = node1->next`.

```
while (curr->next != NULL) {
    while (curr->data > curr->next->data) {
        if (curr == head) {
            prev = curr->next;
            free(curr);
            curr = prev; // after this line (see next comment)...
            curr->next = prev->next; // you do not need this.
            head = prev;
        } else {
            prev = curr->next; // '->next' removed
            temp = curr;
            curr = prev;
            curr->next = prev->next; // needless
            free(temp);
        }
    }

    // tough above code already assigned the next node to curr,
    // below code takes another step forward w/o any test.
    // nested while loops mess here.
    prev = curr; 
    curr = curr->next;
}
```

I think, nested `while` is redundant as well. My choice of code would be:

```
while (curr->next != NULL) {
  if (curr->data <= (curr->next)->data) {
    curr = curr->next;
  }
  else {
    if (curr == head) {
      head = curr->next;
      free(curr);
      curr = head;
    }
    else {
      temp = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
      free(temp);
    }
  }
}
```